# True or false: problems on sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> True or false (if true justify):
>
> 1. if $\{x_n\}$ and $\{x_ny_n\}$ are bounded sequences then $\{y_n\}$ is bounded.
> 2. if $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are sequences such that $x_ny_n \rightarrow 0$ then one of the sequences converges to $0$

Attempt:
1. I know if $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are both bounded then $\{x_ny_n\}$ are bounded. But how to check the reverse. $\{x_n\}$ and $\{x_ny_n\}$ are bounded sequences means $|x_n|<M_1$, $|x_ny_n|<M_2$ for all $n$............

Also help me to solve the second.

Comment: $y_n= \frac{x_ny_n}{x_n}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are there any conditions on the sequences? Because if not:

1. Take $x_n = 0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $y_n$ be any unbounded sequence.
2. Take $x_n$ to be $1, 0, 1, 0, 1, \dots$ and $y_n$ to be $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, \dots$

Answer (score 2):

The pair of sequences $x_n=\frac1n(1-(-1)^n)$, $y_n=n(1+(-1)^n)$ provide a counterexample to both claims.

Answer (score 1):

1) is false take $ x_n = \frac{1}{n}, y_n=n $

2) True suppose not $ x_n , y_n $ are not converging to zero i. e. $ x_n\rightarrow l , y_n\rightarrow r $ let $\epsilon < min ( l, r) $ there exists N such that $|x_n - l | , | y_n - r | < \epsilon $ for all $ n> N$ what can we say about $|x_n y_n| < \epsilon$?

Comment: then $|x_n - l | . | y_n - r | < \epsilon^2$ i.e $|x_ny_n-x_nr-y_nr+lr | < \epsilon^2$ what will be the next step then?

Comment: You are assuming that all sequences converge, which is clearly not true.

Comment: @AmerYR Please explore the 2nd one.

Comment: It by contadiction proof. If the two sequences converging to a non zero number we choose epsilon exactly less than 1/3 of the minimum of (l, r)=m. There exists N $l-\epsilon<x_n<l+\epsilon , r-\epsilon y_n< r+\epsilon $ for all $ N <n $ hence $|x_n| |y_n|(l-\epsilon)(r-\epsilon)>(m-\epsilon)^2>(2/3m)^2> 1/3m>\epsilon $